# Lisp-like string matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm having some trouble with matching strings of this format: `(foo "bar")`. To put it precisely, I wanna capture

1. An opening parenthesis, followed by
2. Zero or more whitespace chars, f.b.
3. At least one word character, f.b
4. Whitespace again, zero or more, f.b.
5. One or more word char, enclosed in double quotes, f.b
6. Optional whitespace, and a closing parenthesis.

Next I wanna extract `foo` and `bar`, but that's a different question. The best I've managed to come up with is `\( [\s]? [\w]+ [\s]? \" [\w]+ \" [\s]? \)`, and I've been using an [online resource](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to check my regex.

Could you please point out what's wrong with my regex?

Comment: "*wrong with my regex*" well, it is you who should describe problem you have with it. We can then try to find cause of problem and solution for it.

Comment: @Pshemo The problem is the regex doesn't match the given specification (steps 1-6); you can also look at the example given in the first sentence. The cause is I haven't figured out regex yet; the solution is to ask for pointers on SO ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "*(symbols included)*"? Which symbols you want to accept inside quotes?

Comment: @Pshemo That's due to my inexperience with regex: I want _all_ characters, including non-word symbols like the double-quote `"`, which would require escaping it, which is a problem for another day. I'll edit the question to simplify matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to enclose [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `\w` or `\s` with `[` `]`, `[\s]` is same as `\s` (only case when you should enclose them with `[` `]` is when you want to create separate character class which combines already existing character classes like `[\s\d]` which represents characters which are whitespaces or digits).
- Also by default spaces are included in regex, so `"\s "` will match two spaces, one for `\s` and one for .
- "*Zero or more*" is represented by `*`, `?` represents zero or once
- If you want to write your regex as String you need to also escape `\` by adding another `\` before it

So try with following regex `"\\(\\s*\\w+\\s*\"[\\w]+\"\\s*\\)"` which represents

```
\\(         - 1. An opening parenthesis
   \\s*     - 2. Zero or more whitespace chars
   \\w+     - 3. At least one word character
   \\s*     - 4. Whitespace again, zero or more
   \"       - 5. opening quotation
   \\w+     - 5. One or more char - I am not sure which symbols you want to add here
                 but you can for instance add them manually with [\\w+\\-*/=<>()]+
   \"       - 5. closing quotation
   \\s*     - 6. Optional whitespace
\\)         - 6. closing parenthesis
```

Now if you want to get some parts of matched text you can use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (surround part you want to match with unescaped parenthesis) like in case of regex `\\w+ (\\w+)` it will find pairs of words, but second word will be placed in group (indexed 1). To get content of that group you just need to use `group(index)` from your `Matcher` instance:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+ (\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ab cd efg hi jk");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("entire match =\t"+matcher.group());
    System.out.println("second word =\t"+matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

output:

```
entire match =  ab cd
second word =   cd
---------------------
entire match =  efg hi
second word =   hi
---------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

There are additional space characters in your regex which are causing the pattern to not match. There is also no need for square brackets. The question mark marks zero or one occurrence *but not more*. To mark zero or more you should use `*`. The below would match the string and the two groups `foo` and `bar` using two matching groups enclosed in parentheses:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\"(\\w*)\"\\s*\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(foo \"bar\")");
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    // foo
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));    // bar
}
```